# How to make BOINC cycle active projects

Tags: macos, distributed-computing, boinc

I have BOINC manager installed on OSX, and I am subscribed to 3 projects

Is there a way to schedule the BOINC manager to cycle between these projects after a certain time with each project?

PS: It does not have to be a BOINC manager setting. I'm OK if there is a way to do it from the command line as well

Answer (score 0):

The boinccmd line utility should give the control you are after, specifically

> --project URL op                   project operation
>      op = reset | detach | update | suspend | resume | nomorework | allowmorework | detach_when_done | dont_detach_when_done

You could then suspend/resume tasks using for instance cron. Type

> crontab -e

Assuming you have the command line version installed in the usual os x location, you can paste something like this (read up on cron for the syntax) to switch from worldcommunitygrid to rosetta at 12:

> 0 12 * * * cd /Library/Application\ Support/BOINC\ Data/ && boinccmd --project www.worldcommunitygrid.org suspend && boinccmd --project boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/ resume

Hopefully this should get you started

Answer (score 0):

BOINC scheduler defines a resource share between projects. If you have three, then each project has a resource share of 33.33%. This means their work will be equally shared.

Now, go to

```
tools > computing preferences
```

and there you have the option `Switch between applications every...`

Just define whatever time you want. Since the resource share is equal and you will have equally the same amount of work units of every project, then probability is the time worked between projects will be the same you defined on the previous option.